# Python: Fetching postgresql result and loading it to JSON

Tags: python, json, postgresql

I'm trying to get details from PostgreSQL about some cameras and I need to insert them all in one JSON response, but I can't imagine how it should be done, because `for row in self.data:` processes one line per time, how can I add them all in one JSON dump?

I imagine JSON dump like this:

```
{
    "status": "ok",
    "total_cameras": 3,
    "cameras":[{
        "camera_id" : 1,
        "camera_name" : "hikvision 1",
        "camera_ip": "42.51.56.0"
        },
        {
            "camera_id" : 2,
            "camera_name" : "hikvision 2",
            "camera_ip": "42.51.56.5"
        },
        {
            "camera_id" : 3,
            "camera_name" : "hikvision 3",
            "camera_ip": "2.1.58.5"
        }]
}
```

My code which I use to get information from PostgreSQL :

```
                if not self.Data:
                    self.RES = {'status': 'nocameras'}
                    return web.Response(text=json.dumps(self.RES), status=403)
                else:
                    self.rows = self.cursor.rowcount
                    for row in self.Data:
                        if self.rows > 1:
                            # Authorizing objects
                            print(row)
                            self.Camera_ID = row[0]
                            self.Camera_Name = row[1]
                            self.Camera_LAT = row[3]
                            self.Camera_LOG = row[4]
                            self.Camera_IP = row[2]
                            self.Camera_Last_Updated = row[6]
                            self.Camera_Street = row[5]
                            self.Camera_API_key = row[7]
                            print(self.Camera_ID, self.Camera_Name)
                        else:
                            self.RES = {'status': 'row_error'}
                            return web.Response(text=json.dumps(self.RES), status=500)
```

Comment: By the way, I see a lot of variables there that are stored as properties of your instance (`self.RES`, `self.rows`, `self.Camera_ID`, etc.) which should probably really be local variables. By storing them on `self`, you're keeping references to everything (until overwritten the next time), preventing garbage collection from doing its job and cluttering up the objects namespace. If you don't need the variables after the method returns, just use `res = ...`, `rows = ...`, etc.

Comment: I have 5 cameras which are stored in the database, let's say the self.Camera_LAT is latitude, so it's basically changing once a minute and with this code, I sent everything to webserver to display all the cameras in the map

Answer (score 0):

I would first use the returned rows to build a list of dictionaries:

```py
cameras = [
    dict(
        camera_id=c_id,
        camera_name=c_name,
        camera_ip=c_ip
    ) for c_id, c_name, _, _, c_ip, *_ in self.Data
]
```

And then create the final JSON object:

```py
json.dumps({
    'status': 'ok',
    'total_cameras': len(cameras),
    'cameras': cameras
})
```